# Android - How to declare a variable for 'this'?

Tags: java, android, class, this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //the problem is here
  private class this_Variable=this;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


  }

  public void quitGame(View v){
    this_Variable.finishAffinity();
  }

}
```

as you can see the code above, I would like to assign 'this' to a variable called 'this_variable'.

I tried the above code, and it doesn't works.

Comment: Could you explain why you want this (pun originally not intended, but now it is)? You can use `this` to refer to the current instance of this class anywhere. Also, the type isn't `class` but `MainActivity`

Comment: because i got problem when write code this.finishAffinity() inside the quitgame(). However, I just solved my problem by your help.. Thanks.. I will share the answer below

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien I think you should use `MainActivity.this.finish()` instead.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just solved the newbie problem... replace class with MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //the problem is here
  private MainActivity this_Variable=this;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


  }

  public void quitGame(View v){
    this_Variable.finishAffinity();
  }

}
```

or just

```
public void quitGame(View v){
  MainActivity.this.finishAffinity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java as well as other programming languages, `this` refers to current instance of the class and its type is the same as the class type.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `quitGame` method `this.finishAffinity()` won't work because you are inside an `onClickListener`, and `this` will refer to that listener. Just simply refer your activity with `MainActivity.this`, and call finish on that.

```
public void quitGame(View v){
    MainActivity.this.finishAffinity();
}
```

It's not a good idea to store your activity as a member variable.